# Replacing scenes when using a UITabBar

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uitabbar

My application has four tabBarItems.  Two of the tabBarItems use CCScene (Cocos2d) classes.  I start on one scene which works well, and then I switch over to the second scene using the tabBar which also works well.  My problem is that when I try to return to the original scene, my view is the first scene but the actual running scene hasn't changed from the second scene.

Is there a way to switch scenes when toggling on a tabBar?

Should each tabBarItem simply link to a CCLayer, and then have all those layers become children to a single CCScene object?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.